# Python - Increasing the number of a variable name...?

Tags: python

For example, I am working with a function with arguments that is comparing a0,a1,a2,a3,a4 to b0,b1,b2,b3,b4.

But I would like to do the same function for all of the arguments.
Example:

```
if a0 > b0:
   do this
elif a0 = b0:
   do this
elif a0 < b0:
   do this
```

In thus, I would like to have the same functions for a1 and b1, a2 and b2...so forth. Is this even possible with increment loop or do I have to manually write it all out? If the question is confusing, please let me know, I can do an edit.

Here is the sample of some of the code that I was given.

```
a0, a1, a2 = input().strip().split(' ')
a0, a1, a2 = [int(a0), int(a1), int(a2)]
```

Comment: Any chance you could just have a list with all your arguments instead of `a0`, `a1`, etc?

Comment: Are the collection of a arguments and b arguments the same length? e.g. if you have 5 a arguments, you will always have 5 b arguments?

Comment: What does your function definition look like? How are you taking these arguments?

Comment: Yes. There will always be 5 arguments for A and B.

Comment: I am stuck with working with 5 continuously-changing arguments. They will always change, so I am not sure on lists or not.

Comment: In addition to the answers below, you might find the function `zip` helpful: `map(func, zip(all_a, all_b))` where func looks like `def func( (a, b) ): do stuff`

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your function for *`2` parameters only* has the name`func_a_b()`. For example:

```
def func_a_b(a, b):
    if a > b:
       print(a, "is greater than", b)
    elif a == b:
       print(a, "is the same as",  b)
    elif a < b:
       print(a, "is less than",    b)
```

**The solution:** Define a function with *variable numbers of parameters*:

```
def func(*arguments):
    half   = len(arguments) // 2
    a_list = arguments[0:half]             # [a0, a1, a2, ...]
    b_list = arguments[half:]              # [b0, b1, b2, ...]

    for a, b in zip(a_list, b_list):       # [(a0, b0), (a1, b1), (a2, b2), ...]
        func_a_b(a,b)                      # Calling your original function in the loop
```

It is all.

---

You may try it, for example:

```
a0 = 10
a1 = 11
a2 = 12 
b0 = 20 
b1 = 10
b2 = 12

func(a0, a1, a2, b0, b1, b2)
```

The output will be

> 10 is less than 20
>   11 is greater than 10
>   12 is the same as 12

---

**The explanation:**

So, what does the function `func()` do?

In its first statement

```
    half   = len(arguments) // 2
```

it gets the *list of its arguments* (which has the name `arguments`), then calculates the *number of its items* (`len ( arguments )`, and halves it (`len(arguments) // 2`) (by integer division (`//`) to obtain the *integer* result).

The next 2 statements

```
    a_list   = arguments[0:half]
    b_list   = arguments[half:]
```

gets first and second half of the arguments of the function `func()`.
(The first half are for example your `a0`, `a1`, `a2`, `a3`, the second half are `b0`, `b1`, `b2`, `b3`.)

And, finally, the loop

```
    for a, b in zip(a_list, b_list):
        func_a_b(a, b)
```

will sequentially call the `func_a_b()` function for the pairs `(a0, b0)`, `(a1, b1)`, etc., *which was your goal*.

*Note:* You may use a shorter form:

```
     for pair in zip(a_list, b_list):
         func_a_b(*pair)
```

Comment: I like your code! Two comments, though. Using extra whitespace to vertically align assignments is discouraged by [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#whitespace-in-expressions-and-statements). Similarly, whitespace after open parentheses is a no-no. That's all style, though. The only practical change is that since `len(some_list)` cannot by definition be less than zero, truncating its half is always exactly equal to flooring its half (i.e. floor division works better than casting to int! `len(arguments) // 2`)

Comment: @AdamSmith - Thank you very much! Indeed I did't carefully read PEP8 about vertically align assignment, so I did it now. The whitespace *after* opening parantheses is probably OK (correct me, please, if PEP8 don't approve it) - I didn't use it for years, it is my new style learned from some nice book about Python. And I'm going to improve my code by your last note.

Comment: "Avoid extraneous whitespace in the following situations: Immediately inside parentheses, brackets or braces." That's the first section in the link I gave you :). PEP8 is all just a style *guide* but since experienced Pythonistas tend to follow PEP8, it kind of makes your code look more Pythonic by definition.

Comment: @AdamSmith - Oh, you are right again, thanks! So I will return to my previous, correct style and I have to read PEP8 once more. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use two lists?

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i] > b[i]:
        do this
    elif a[i] == b[i]:
        do this
    elif a[i] < b[i]:
        do this
```

This requires lists `a` and `b` to contain the same number of elements.

And you can apply a `break` if you need to stop upon some condition.

Comment: I would prefer `for i, aa in enumerate(a): bb = b[i]; if aa > bb: # etc`

Comment: Or better still: `for aa, bb in zip(a, b):`

Answer (score 0):

You can just make a function that accepts two arguments and just do like it's supposed to do. Then, just call the function multiple times like below:

```
def f(a, b):
   if a > b:
      do this
   elif a = b:
      do this
   elif a < b:
      do this

f(a0, b0)
f(a1, b1)
f(a2, b2)
f(a3, b3)
f(a4, b4)
```

It's even better if you store the variables in a list so that you can simply iterate it.

Answer (score 0):

The `split` method you are using returns a list of values.
Instead of

```
a0, a1, a2 = input().strip().split(' ')
```

You can use

```
aValues = input().strip().split(' ')
```

To quickly convert all the values to integers, you can use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

```
aValues = [int(a) for a in input().strip().split(' ')]
```

This just loops through the list created by the `split` function and gives you a list containing just the `int` forms of each element.

Then, as mentioned in [0605002's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44611014/2773311), you can just loop through the lists in your function and write the comparison code once.

```
def (aValues, bValues):
    for i in range(len(aValues)):
        if aValues[i] > bValues[i]:
            #do this
        elif aValues[i] == bValues[i]:
            #do this
        else: #also, you can just put else here because if a is neither bigger nor equal to b, it must be smaller
            #do this
```

I'm not sure what you meant by 'continuously changing arguments' in your comment, but lists in Python are mutable, so you can just change the elements if you need to.

```
aValues[3] += 4 #increase a3 by 4
aValues[4], aValues[3] = aValues[3], aValues[4] #swap a3 and a4
#or whatever else you have to do
```